# Relative Xpath Not Work In Maven TestNg But Absolute Path Works

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

**Before installing/using** Maven plugins, all absolute & relative paths worked in testNG. But **After using** maven, Relative Xpath not worked.
Even I tried by my own Relative Xpath but not worked. 
I used Eclipse IDE for JAVA, Selenium 3.141.59 . Here I attached my 2 codes of **src/main/java** and **src/test/java respectively**.

phpTravelsLoginPage.java

```
package sqa;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class phpTravelsLoginPage {
    WebDriver driver;

/* Here This Below XPath works  */ 
    By MyAccount = By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/ul[2]/ul/li[1]/a");
    By loginBtn = By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/ul[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a");

/* But Here This Below XPath works  */ 
//  By MyAccount = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"li_myaccount\"]/a");
//  By loginBtn = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"li_myaccount\"]/ul/li[]/a");


    public phpTravelsLoginPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    // CLick on MyAccount Dropdown
    public void clickOnMyAccount()
    {
        driver.findElement(MyAccount).click();
    }

    // CLick on Login Dropdown button
    public void clickOnLoginButton()
    {
        driver.findElement(loginBtn).click();
    }


    /* This loginToPhptravels method will be exposed to the Test Case  */ 

    public void loginToPhptravels() throws InterruptedException

    {
        // Click on the MyAccount Dropdown
        this.clickOnMyAccount();

        // Click on the Login dropdown menu
        this.clickOnLoginButton();
    }
}
```

loginTest.java

```
package sqa;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

import sqa.phpTravelsLoginPage;

public class loginTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    phpTravelsLoginPage php;
  @Test
  public void f() throws InterruptedException {
      driver.get("https://phptravels.net");
      php = new phpTravelsLoginPage(driver);
      php.loginToPhptravels();
  }
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\geckodriver.exe");
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");

      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
  }
}
```

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sqa</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqa</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Note : TestNG installed by "Install New Software" , not through maven.

[image: Project Maven]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testcases having absolute xpaths are not very consistent in execution, it is recommended that Do Not Use absolute Xpath, and it is nothing to do with installing maven. After searching little bit found below working and unique matches of xpaths hope those will work for you!!!

`By myaccount = By.xpath(".//a[@href='https://www.phptravels.net/']/ancestor::div[2]//a[text()=' My Account ']");

By Login = By.xpath(".//a[text()=' My Account ' and @aria-expanded]/following-sibling::ul//a[text()=' Login']");`